# PHP Contact/Order form not working (switch statement)

Tags: php, email, switch-statement, contact-form

I have tried to find a solution to this for about a week now. It is highly likely that I have come across a correct answer and not understood it because, frankly, I know nothing about PHP. So I would be truly grateful for some assistance.

I am updating my father's website and am trying to fit together my existing code for a contact form and some code by the person who did his original website and I cannot get the order to send (all the contact details come through fine but the order itself shows up as 'Array')

Essentially, the switch function should swap out the name of the item and add it to the order, provided a quantity has been given.

I hope that makes sense!

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$tellimus = array();

function kirjuta_mail($input){

    while ($rida = array_pop($input)){
        $vastus .= "Tellin: ".$rida[0].": ".$rida[1]." tk.\n";
    } 

    $vastus .="\n\n $name\n $email\n $tel\n $address\n\n Kommentaar: $message\n\n";

}    

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $kaart = $_POST['kaart'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $headers = "From: Saar Graafika lehelt \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
    $to = 'email@email.com'; 
    $subject = 'Tellimus Saar Graafika lehelt';

    $body = "\n $kaart\n\n $name\n $email\n $tel\n $address\n\n Kommentaar: $message\n\n";

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid e-mail address';
}
    if (!$_POST['tel']) {
    $errTel = 'Please enter your phone number';
}
    if (!$_POST['address']) {
    $errAddress = 'Please enter your address';
}
    if ($human !== 8) {
    $errHuman = 'The anti-spam is incorrect';
}
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errTel && !$errAddress && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you for your order - we'll be in touch soon!</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">We are sorry - there's been an error. Please try again later!</div>';
    }
}
    }
        function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
           '(\r+)',
           '(\t+)',
           '(%0A+)',
           '(%0D+)',
           '(%08+)',
           '(%09+)'
           );

    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";

    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

if(IsInjected($email))
{
    echo "We are sorry - there's been an error!";
    exit;
}

    if($checkme) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < 139; $i++){

            if (strlen($_POST['kaart'][$i])) {

                  switch ($i) {
                      case 0:
                          array_push($tellimus,array("kaart113", $_POST['kaart'][$i]));
                          break;
                            LOTS MORE ITEMS HERE
                          case 146:
                          array_push($tellimus,array("Challenges: CD ", $_POST['kaart'][$i]));
                          break;                          
                  }
            }
        }

    if (count($input) == 0)
        kirjuta_mail($tellimus);   
    }
?>
```

**These bits are from the original code:**

```
session_start();

$tellimus = array();

function kirjuta_mail($input){

    while ($rida = array_pop($input)){
        $vastus .= "Tellin: ".$rida[0].": ".$rida[1]." tk.\n";
    } 

    $vastus .="\n\n $name\n $email\n $tel\n $address\n\n Kommentaar: $message\n\n";

}
```

**And:**

```
if($checkme) {

for ($i = 0; $i < 139; $i++){

    if (strlen($_POST['kaart'][$i])) {

          switch ($i) {
              case 0:
                  array_push($tellimus,array("kaart113", $_POST['kaart'][$i]));
                  break;
                    LOTS MORE ITEMS HERE
                  case 146:
                  array_push($tellimus,array("Challenges: CD ", $_POST['kaart'][$i]));
                  break;                          
          }
    }
}

if (count($input) == 0)
    kirjuta_mail($tellimus);   
}
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="telli.php">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
            <a class="acca" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne"><div class="panel-heading kaks">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> J&otilde;ulukaardid: A4 kokkumurtud <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down ava"></span></h4>
            </div></a>
            <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">                                         
                    <p>Formaat: A4 kokkumurtud &nbsp;&#124;&nbsp; Hind: <span class="uus">0.90&euro;</span></p>
                    <div class="tellimus">
                        <a href="img/tooted/kaardid/postkaart/kaart136_A5.jpg" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-collapseInnerOne"><img src="img/tooted/kaardid/postkaart/kaart136_A5.jpg" class="kesku postkaart" alt=""></a>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Kogus:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control kogus" id="kogus" name=kaart[15] placeholder="0">&nbsp;tk
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-form-label">E-mail<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                    <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tel" class="col-form-label">Phone<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                    <input name="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone Number" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel']); ?>">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errTel</p>";?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address" class="col-form-label">Address<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="address" placeholder="Your address"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']); ?></textarea>
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errAddress</p>";?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="col-form-label">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']); ?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="human" class="col-form-label">&#42;How much is 3+5? (Anti-spam)<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Answer">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="checkme" value="formmail">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Place Order">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $result; ?>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: where are you storing the "order"? "...get the order to send (all the contact details come through fine but the order itself shows up as 'Array')"

Comment: From what I understand from the original coder's comments, the order should be stored in $tellimus = array();

Answer (score 0):

The order is supposed to be stored in  $_POST['kaart'], it means you need a checkboxes  grouped together using the same name to add orders in your form, which customers will click to select items to order and the loop is used to add the selected items to the $tellimus array for it to be sent to the mail function

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your script.  Unfortunately I will not be able to explain all in detail here.  As you are using HTML5 form elements, I have added attribute 'required' in the mandatory fields. So the form will not submit if these are not filled.

```
        <form role="form" method="post"  action="telli.php">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <a class="acca" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne"><div class="panel-heading kaks">
                <h4 class="panel-title"> J&otilde;ulukaardid: A4 kokkumurtud <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down ava"></span></h4>
                    </div></a>
                    <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">                                         
                            <p>Formaat: A4 kokkumurtud &nbsp;&#124;&nbsp; Hind: <span class="uus">0.90&euro;</span></p>
                            <div class="tellimus">
                                <a href="img/tooted/kaardid/postkaart/kaart136_A5.jpg" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-collapseInnerOne"><img src="img/tooted/kaardid/postkaart/kaart136_A5.jpg" class="kesku postkaart" alt=""></a>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-form-label">Kogus:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control kogus" id="kogus" name=kaart[15] placeholder="0">&nbsp;tk
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-form-label">E-mail<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="" requird>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tel" class="col-form-label">Phone<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                <input name="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone Number" value="" required>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address" class="col-form-label">Address<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="address" placeholder="Your address" required></textarea>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="col-form-label">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="human" class="col-form-label">&#42;How much is 3+5? (Anti-spam)<span class="uus">&#42;</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Answer" required>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="checkme" value="formmail">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Place Order">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php if(isset($result)) {echo $result;} ?>
        </div>
    </form>
```

After form submission, your script sent the email even before it took care of all those order elements.  That is why you got Array for order. I have changed the order in which things are executed and also changed the coding to take care of order elements. Hope this helps..

```
            <?php
            session_start();

            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
                   // echo "$key => $val <br/>\n";
                }
            $kaart = $_POST['kaart'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $tel = $_POST['tel'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $human = intval($_POST['human']);
            $headers = "From: Saar Graafika lehelt \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
            $to = 'email@email.com'; 
            $subject = 'Tellimus Saar Graafika lehelt';

            $body = "Name = $name\n Email = $email\n Tel = $tel\n address = $address\n\n Kommentaar: $message\n\n";

            if(IsInjected($email))
            {
                echo "We are sorry - there's been an error!";
                exit;
            }


            $kart = "";
            foreach($_POST['kaart'] as $key => $val) {
                if($val!==0){
                    $kart .= "kaart".$key."=$val\n";
                }
            }

            $body .= "\n\n$kart";

            echo nl2br($body) ;

                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you for your order - we\'ll be in touch soon!</div>';
                } else {
                    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">We are sorry - there\'s been an error. Please try again later!</div>';
                }

            }

            function IsInjected($str)
            {
            $injections = array('(\n+)',
                   '(\r+)',
                   '(\t+)',
                   '(%0A+)',
                   '(%0D+)',
                   '(%08+)',
                   '(%09+)'
                   );

            $inject = join('|', $injections);
            $inject = "/$inject/i";

            if(preg_match($inject,$str))
            {
              return true;
            }
            else
            {
              return false;
            }
        }


        ?>
```